# How to Set Outhtml for Gecko Browes in C#

Tags: c#, browser, flash, geckofx

I want to display swf files on webbrowser. as I know that I cant do that with MS Webbrowser so  I am using gecko and I tried to open a website and swf file worked.

But there is one problem, I want to use an embed code for displaying swf file. But I can not find documentText or outhtml property in Gecko 16.0 . I read something about it and had been said that outhtml doesnt supported upper gecko 11.0, so I am looking for an alternative way to do that?

I tried like that but didnt worked

```
geckoWebBrowser1.DomDocument.TextContent = "<html><body><h1>Hello !!!</h1></body></html>";
```

Well how can I embed a html code to geckowebbrowser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my own problem  :)

it had been so easy..

```
geckoWebBrowser1.LoadHtml("<html><body><h1>Hello!!!</h1></body></html>");
```

thts all and it works in gecko 16.0 too :)

Answer (score 3):

You use `GeckoHtmlElement InnerHtml` property.

This can be used after a document has been loaded and used to update the document without reloading the whole document.

For example:

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = "<h1>Hello!!!</h1>";
```